# Go Yaml Interpretation Example

Tags: go, yaml

This Go Yaml Interpretation Example, 
https://gist.github.com/suntong001/74c85d15b19ef4b14b0e, can unmarshal a simple YAML like this:

```
foo: 1
bar:
  - one
  - two
```

Now I want to interpretation an array of the exact same data structure, what's the correct way to do?

Below is my code so far, and it is not working as expected. Please help.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Config struct {
    Foo string
    Bar []string
}

type Configs struct {
    Cfgs []Config
}

var data = `
- foo: 1
  bar:
    - one
    - two
    - three
- foo: 2
  bar:
    - one1
    - two2
    - three3
`

func main() {

  var config Configs

    /*
       filename := os.Args[1]
       source, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
       if err != nil {
           panic(err)
       }
    */

    source := []byte(data)

    err := yaml.Unmarshal(source, &config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }

    //fmt.Printf("Value: %#v\n", config.Bar[0])

    fmt.Printf("--- config:\n%v\n\n", config)
}
```

UPDATE:

To make it work, Jfly pointed out, simply replace my `var config Configs` with `var config []Config`, and it does the trick. Now I think if change my data definition to the following, my above code would work.

```
foobars:
 - foo: 1
   bar:
    - one
    - two
    - three

 - foo: 2
   bar:
    - one1
    - two2
    - three3
```

Nops, it doesn't. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the example yaml file are sequence of objects, so do it like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Config struct {
    Foo string
    Bar []string
}

var data = `
- foo: 1
  bar:
    - one
    - two
    - three
- foo: 2
  bar:
    - one1
    - two2
    - three3
`

func main() {

    var config []Config

    /*
       filename := os.Args[1]
       source, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
       if err != nil {
           panic(err)
       }
    */

    source := []byte(data)

    err := yaml.Unmarshal(source, &config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }

    //fmt.Printf("Value: %#v\n", config.Bar[0])

    fmt.Printf("--- config:\n%v\n\n", config)
}
```

As to your updated question, your code almost works, just give a hint to the yaml parser like this:

```
type Configs struct {
    Cfgs []Config `foobars`
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but I'm still wondering why. I thought that `var config []Config` would be the same as my `var config Configs` which is of type `[]Config`, isn't it? What's the difference? Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not the same. `var config Configs` means [mapping scalars to sequences](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963).

Comment: Hmm... I still don't quite get it. Let me put it this way, what if I need to incorporate this array in a more complicated data structure? I've updated my data def to reflect the simplest way to nest it, I thought my code would work, but I was wrong again. Please help.

Comment: @xpt See my edit and upvote the answer if it helps you out :-)

Comment: Sure, was waiting for the closure. Definitely +1. Thanks